# JNLP4 Connect Error - Connection closed before acknowledgement sent

Tags: jenkins

This seems very similar to a recently closed #57143. We have spent quite a bit of time troubleshooting it though not able to find the root case. We had nginx and replace that by elb and both cases leads to same problem below. Please let me know what additional logs/info are needed and will provide. Any help/support/guidance is appreciated.

### Env/Setup

Agent: OSX Mojave 10.14.5
Jenkins: Linux (Jenkins LTS 2.176.3)
Java on agent:
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_212-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.212-b03, mixed mode)

Java on master:
java.runtime.name   OpenJDK Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version    1.8.0_222-b10
java.version    1.8.0_222
java.vm.info    mixed mode
java.vm.name    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

---

netcat from slave towards master.
$ nc -z jenkins.infrastructure.XXXXX.care 50000

Connection to jenkins.infrastructure.XXXXX.care port 50000 [tcp/*] succeeded!

## ELB

kubectl -n infrastructure get svc
infrastructure-nginx-ingress-internal-controller LoadBalancer 100.66.210.45 internal-ab39ee254472111e9aa5b0a4f0f93d47-951468028.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com 80:30664/TCP,443:30937/TCP,50000:32123/TCP 166d

Logs
Aug 31, 2019 7:39:48 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine

INFO: Setting up agent: ICL-Slave

Aug 31, 2019 7:39:48 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener

INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.

Aug 31, 2019 7:39:48 PM hudson.remoting.Engine startEngine

INFO: Using Remoting version: 3.29

Aug 31, 2019 7:39:48 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir

INFO: Using /Users/vmccbuild/jenkins/remoting as a remoting work directory

Aug 31, 2019 7:39:48 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Locating server among https://jenkins.infrastructure.xxxxx.care/

Aug 31, 2019 7:39:48 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver resolve

INFO: Remoting server accepts the following protocols: [JNLP4-connect, Ping]

Aug 31, 2019 7:39:48 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Agent discovery successful

Agent address: jenkins.infrastructure.xxxxx.care

Agent port:    50000

Identity:      6b:c4:c2:2b:ed:b7:da:bc:72:58:c8:83:dd:d0:67:46

Aug 31, 2019 7:39:48 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Handshaking

Aug 31, 2019 7:39:48 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Connecting to jenkins.infrastructure.xxxxx.care:50000

Aug 31, 2019 7:39:49 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP4-connect

Aug 31, 2019 7:39:59 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Protocol JNLP4-connect encountered an unexpected exception

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ConnectionRefusalException: Connection closed before acknowledgement sent

at org.jenkinsci.remoting.util.SettableFuture.get(SettableFuture.java:223)

at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:614)

at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:474)

Caused by: org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ConnectionRefusalException: Connection closed before acknowledgement sent

at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.AckFilterLayer.onRecvClosed(AckFilterLayer.java:280)

at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.FilterLayer.abort(FilterLayer.java:164)

at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.AckFilterLayer.access$000(AckFilterLayer.java:43)

at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.AckFilterLayer$1.run(AckFilterLayer.java:176)

at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.IOHub$DelayedRunnable.run(IOHub.java:964)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:93)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Aug 31, 2019 7:39:59 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Connecting to jenkins.infrastructure.xxxxx.care:50000

Aug 31, 2019 7:39:59 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Server reports protocol JNLP4-plaintext not supported, skipping

Aug 31, 2019 7:39:59 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Server reports protocol JNLP3-connect not supported, skipping

Aug 31, 2019 7:39:59 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Server reports protocol JNLP2-connect not supported, skipping

Aug 31, 2019 7:39:59 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Server reports protocol JNLP-connect not supported, skipping

Aug 31, 2019 7:39:59 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error

SEVERE: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted

java.lang.Exception: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted

at hudson.remoting.Engine.onConnectionRejected(Engine.java:682)

at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:639)

at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:474)

Answer (score 1):

Solution to this problem: tunnel through the ELB as to get slave/master connected. How to do this?

Go to Jenkins Master → Nodes →  → Advanced → Tunnel: ernal-aef67c013ca2d11e9b6ab02485d01370-111334679.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com:50000 
(Above takes for granted that security group/inbound has also been properly configured)

This assumes that you have already configured agent port static to 50000 - how? Jenkins -> global security -> Agents -> TCP port for inbound agents -> Fixed: 50000

Answer (score 0):

FYI in case it helps any – I just had to go through a big diag effort on my site with a bunch of windows JNLP agents that stopped working sometime in past few days with the same above failures/errors.

After a long set of rabbit trails - what I found in my case – the problem wound up being reverse DNS resolution stopped working (unrelated local problem – "It's always DNS", right?) - but that inability to reverse resolve the connecting client (windows box) was causing the JNLP server side to drop the connection.

Just wanted to add this here in case it helps anyone else with future similar issues if it happens to be related.

Answer (score 0):

I have Jenkins behind a NGINX (using https) and the problem was that the Java agent uses TCP to communicate and not HTTPs. I tried to configure NGINX to do an [SSL Pass-Thru](https://serversforhackers.com/c/tcp-load-balancing-with-nginx-ssl-pass-thru) but it didn't work for me.

Finally I end-up creating a Network Load Balancer (AWS) and using the dns name in the Advanced configuration of the Jenkins Node so that it uses this LB to go to the Jenkins server using TCP and not HTTP as the main protocol.